# Specified child already has a parent

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, fragment

The User clicks a button and the data from editText's are sent to this fragment.
This data should be put into a new table row but i always get this logcat after clicking the button that sends the data to this fragment:

```
Process: com.example.nlp_expense_tracker, PID: 32439
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5235)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5064)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5004)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4976)
```

This is my fragment where the recieved data is processed:

```
class HistoryFragment : Fragment() {

private val dataStore = ArrayList<String>()
private val dataAmount = ArrayList<String>()
private val dataDate = ArrayList<String>()

private lateinit var store: TextView
private lateinit var amount: TextView
private lateinit var date: TextView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?):
        View {val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false)

    date= view.findViewById(R.id.date)
    store= view.findViewById(R.id.store)
    amount = view.findViewById(R.id.amount)

    val table : TableLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tableHistorie)
    val row : TableRow = view.findViewById(R.id.tableRowOne)

    // Use the Kotlin extension in the fragment-ktx artifact
    setFragmentResultListener("requestKey") { requestKey, bundle ->
        // We use a String here, but any type that can be put in a Bundle is supported
        val result = bundle.getString("bundleKey")
        dataStore.add(result.toString())
        for(i in dataStore.indices)
        {
            val storeName = dataStore [i]
            store.text = storeName
        }
        row.addView(store)
        table.addView(row)
    }
    setFragmentResultListener("requestKey2") { requestKey, bundle ->
        // We use a String here, but any type that can be put in a Bundle is supported
        val result2 = bundle.getString("bundleKey2")
        // Do something with the result
        dataAmount.add(result2.toString())
        for(i in dataAmount.indices)
        {
            val storeName = dataAmount [i]
            amount.text = storeName
        }
        row.addView(amount)
        table.addView(row)
    }
    setFragmentResultListener("requestKey3") { requestKey, bundle ->
        // We use a String here, but any type that can be put in a Bundle is supported
        val result3 = bundle.getString("bundleKey3")
        // Do something with the result
        dataDate.add(result3.toString())
        for(i in dataDate.indices)
        {
            val storeName = dataDate [i]
            date.text = storeName
        }
        row.addView(date)
        table.addView(row)
    }
    return view
}
}
```

And the XML for this fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableHistorie"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:stretchColumns="+"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRowOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/store"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Store" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Amount spent" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Did you want to add those results in the same Row? Or new Row for every result?

Comment: Same row but different column.

Comment: Then just remove table.addView(row) from your listeners.

Comment: @dkiwikid Did you solve a problem ?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false)` creates view hierarchy like on image above (create instances of views objects from xml).
2. `view.findViewById` return view which already exist in `view` or null if it doesn't exist.
3. When framework adds some view to parent it writes reference of parent to child view but before check if child view already have parent (reference to parent) in `ViewGroup.addViewInner` and `View.assignParent` methods.

What did you do: you take view which exist (drawed on screen) and try put it to tableRowOne ones more. You cant do this.

I have a suggestion what did you really want to do: add new row to tableView. If I'm right you have some options:

1. By each create new instance of TableRow and 3 instance of TextView then put textviews to new TableRow and then add them to table like:

```
table.addView(
    TableRow().apply{
      addView(TextView())
      addView(TextView())
      addView(TextView())

    }
  )
```

2. Use same approach as in paragraph 1 bu put your row layout in separate xml with name for example "row_layout.xml".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tableRowOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/store"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Store" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Amount spent" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date" />
    </TableRow>
```

then include row layout in your main layout [by using tag include:](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts)

```
...
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRowOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <include layout="@layout/row_layout" />
....
```

But main sense of separate layout file is [using layout inflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater) to create new row:

```
val newRow: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, table, false)
val newstore= newRow.findViewById(R.id.store)
newstore.text = "some text"
table.add(newRow)
```

3. I think that the best way it is to [use RecyclerView](http://Create%20dynamic%20lists%20with%20RecyclerView) for you table. Your row will be a [view of ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#implement-adapter). [Google sample app with recyclerView](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/main/RecyclerViewKotlin/).

Comment: Thanks for that elaborated answer! Will Look into the recycler and spent probably the whole of tomorrow for it.

Comment: You're welcome! If you will have a problem plead let me know )